# rostopic hz doesn't work when using playing from a bag

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure if my problem is similiar to [1], but this have been flagged as solved and I still have it in Fuerte.

I follow the tutorial "MappingFromLoggedData" at [2], and after I start "rosbag play ..." if I do a "rostopic hz /tf" there is no output.

The map gets generated correctly, so everthing else is fine!

[1] trac/ros/ticket/2950
[2] wiki/slam_gmapping/Tutorials/MappingFromLoggedData

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51052/rostopic-hz-doesn%27t-work-when-using-playing-from-a-bag/) by [nunojpg](https://answers.ros.org/users/3842/nunojpg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2012-12-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried playing with rosbag play --clock?

rostopic hz requires a time component.  If the 'use_sim_time' parameter is set to true, you need to publish the time using rosbag play --clock.

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2012-12-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2